# QuTip: How to multiply symbol with matrix

Tags: programming, qutip

I am trying to multiply a symbol with a matrix which is defined by QuTip quantum object, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Incompatible object for multiplication
```

I used:

```
from qutip import *
import sympy as sp
w0 = sp.Symbol('\omega_{0}')
w0*destroy(4)
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: cross-posted on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70490407/4063051. And incidentally, I think this question is better suited there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can either convert `destroy(4)` to a sympy matrix or a numpy array like that:

```
a = destroy(4)
destroy_ = sp.Matrix(a)
destroy_ = w0*destroy_
destroy_
```

And here is the result :[image]

or try numpy array:

```
destroy = np.array(a)
result = w0*destroy
```

After you finished all stuff (like finding w0 or doing all computations), then, you can convert your final matrix to Qobj